# How to avoid adding of button multiple times which was created dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement where I need to show a button labeled Set only when both the text in two  Text input fields are the same.
I am able to show the button Set which is created dynamically When clicked on the Validate button .

The Only issue i am seeing is that , the Set button is being added multiple times when ever if clicked on the Validate button

```
$(function () {
    $("#setcategory").hide();
    $(document).on('click', '#validate', function (event) {
        var val1 = $("#fort1text").val();
        var val2 = $("#fort2text").val();
        if (val1 != '' && val2 != '') {
            if (val1 == val2) {
                var setthiscategory = '<input type="button" id="setthiscategory" class="saveclassbtn btn blue" id="sett1cat" value="Set This Category"/>';

                $("#validate").after(setthiscategory);

            } else {

            }
        }
    });

});
```

Please let me know how to resolve this ??

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1):

use length in jquery ,to find that element was created or not

```
if($("#setthiscategory").length==0){
      $( "#validate" ).after(setthiscategory);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add an `if` statement to verify that you perform the action only if `#setthiscategory` doesn't exist:

```
if (!$('#setthiscategory').length)
    $( "#validate" ).after(setthiscategory);
```

hope that helps.

Comment: The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use length instead

Comment: @axel.michel this is right. changed `.size()` to `.length`

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<input type="text" id="fort1text" class="m-wrap span12" placeholder="">
    <input type="text" id="fort2text" class="m-wrap span12" placeholder="">
    <input type="button" id="validate" value="Validate">
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $("#setcategory").hide();
        });
        $(document).on('click', '#validate', function (event) { 
            var val1 = $("#fort1text").val();
            var val2 = $("#fort2text").val();
            if(val1!=''&&val2!='')
            {
            if(val1==val2)
            {  
        var setthiscategory = '<input type="button" id="setthiscategory" class="saveclassbtn btn blue" id="sett1cat" value="Set This Category"/>';
              if($("#setthiscategory").length==0)
                $( "#validate" ).after(setthiscategory);
            }
            else
            {
               $('#setthiscategory').remove();
            }
            }
        });

    </script>
```